# i am tried to deploy my angular+nest js application in aws ec2, can i know the steps for deploying

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2, deployment, nestjs, hosting

i have cloned and build my app both angular and nest js

```
"build:prod": "nest build && cd ../frontend && ng build --configuration=production --output-path ../backend/dist/frontend && cd ../backend",
```

used this in my backend to build both on same time and the frontend file is now with the backend dist folder
[[dist folder backend structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6oAd.png)]

[nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK9ha.png)

in the ngnix config

```
location / {
    # Serve frontend files
    root /home/ubuntu/E-learn/backend/dist/frontend;
    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

when i tried to add this line to access the frontend file , i got internal server error, before that my nginx page was showing..

can i get any guidance how to host it. or the issue with the nginx configuration.

Comment: I can't help with your exact issue, but generally a good way to host static websites on AWS is with S3 buckets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: i have found a solution, thanks for the response..